# Salvar dados em uma ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, onde eu possuo uma ViewBag listando uma lista de números, do meu banco de dados.

Necessito gravar o número selecionado neste dropdown, em outra ViewBag.
Não sei como fazer isso, alguém teria como me ajudar?

ViewBag retornando a lista de números:

```
ViewBag.Contrato = usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(u => u.sLogin == autenticacaoProvider.UsuarioAutenticado.Login).Select(u => u.SqContrato);
```

View com o DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Contrato", new SelectList(ViewBag.Contrato, "Contrato"))
```

Existe alguma sintaxe, como "@Html.DropDownListFor(@ViewBag)"?

Comment: Ih ai tudo bem? O funcionamento aqui do fórum é um pouco diferente de outros fóruns. Quando for solicitar alguma informação do post use a opção **Comentar**. No caso respostas seriam somente as respostas para o post. Dê uma visualizada em  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour para mais informações e se familiarizar. E bem vindo a comunidade.

Comment: Desculpe a falta de conhecimento. A partir de agora, usarei o fórum corretamente.

Comment: Eu também fiz muita confusão no início. Sou o Jothaz você se lembra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternativamente à resposta do @PauloHDSouza, não é preciso usar `ExpandoObject` para retornar um objeto do banco. A inferência dinâmica do C# já resolve este problema:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var lista =  usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(u => u.sLogin == autenticacaoProvider.UsuarioAutenticado.Login).Select(u => u.SqContrato);

    return View(lista);
}
```

Obviamente, é preciso configurar `@model` no início da View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Usuario>
```

Comment: Interessante, nao sabia deste modo. +1

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

No controller faça

```
  public ActionResult Index(){
    dynamic model = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    model.Lista =  usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(u => u.sLogin == autenticacaoProvider.UsuarioAutenticado.Login).Select(u => u.SqContrato);

return View(model);
}
```

E na view basta chamar

```
@Model.Lista
```

para acessar a lista, para fazer um DropDownBox, tem um modo que é na mão.

```
<select>
@foreach(var item in Model.Lista){
 <option value="item.valor">item.texto</option>
}
</select>
```

Me desculpe caso tenha algum erro de sintaxe, fiz tudo aqui sem jogar no visual studio.

Comment: Até esta parte, já havia conseguido chegar. Necessito agora que o usuário escolha uma opção, e eu consiga salvar esta opção em algum tipo de variável global( ViemBag, ViewModel, ou algo do tipo), para que possa usar em uma consulta.

Comment: Faça uma outra pergunta e explica colocando código por favor.

Comment: refiz a pergunta, explicando melhor meu cenário.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46382/salvar-dados-em-uma-viari%C3%A1vel-global

Comment: Se esta resposta aqui te ajudou, marque como correta.