# Salvar dados em uma "Viariável Global"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Olá, 
Possuo um DropDownList, vindo de uma ViewBag, e necessito gravar esse valor em algum tipo de "variável global". Pesquisei e vi que as melhores formas de fazer isso, é gravando em uma ViewBag ou em uma ViewModel.

Cenário: Ao usuário logar no sistema, ele terá de escolher qual contrato ele quer acessar( em um DropDownList). Necessito que esse valor fique salvo, e e que possa utilizar ele em uma consulta logo após, para mostrar os dados apenas deste contrato.
O login está funcionando corretamente, e consegui listar os contratos em um DropDownList, vindo de uma viewbag.
Preciso apenas pegar esse valor selecionado e usar em outra consulta.

Código do DropDownList:

```
            ViewBag.Contrato = usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(u => u.sLogin == autenticacaoProvider.UsuarioAutenticado.Login).Select(u => u.SqContrato);
```

View chamando o DropDownList:

```
        @Html.DropDownList("Contrato", new SelectList(ViewBag.Contrato, "Contrato"))
```

Estou com dificuldades, em criar o método no controller que irá salvar este falor, para que eu possa usar-lo novamente.

Se precisar de mais código, basta comentar, que posto aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No post de seu formulário (pode ser `GET` sim), você pode tratar o código em seu controller da seguinte forma:

```
public class ContaController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult SelecionarContrato(int Contrato)
  {
        Session["contrato"] = model.Contrato;
        //Some code here...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

 public ActionResult VerificarContrato()
 {
      var contrato = (int)Session["contrato"];

 }
}
```

O método `VerificarContrato` é um exemplo de recuperação da informação. Após coloca-lo na *session*, verifique se o objeto está nulo e faça os devidos tratamentos. No exemplo está um inteiro, mas você pode armazenar objetos complexos também.

Comment: Neste método eu estou recebendo um "'System.NullReferenceException' ".
Coloquei um writeline para checar, e está voltando como nullo, ao chegar no "var contrato = (int)Session["contrato"];", recebe sempre 0, e recebo esse erro

Answer (score 2):

Faça uma atribuição a `Session` no seu Controller:

```
public ActionResult Exemplo(int Contrato) {
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Contrato"] = Contrato;

    ...
}
```

Recuperando o valor:

```
public ActionResult OutroExemplo() {
     var Contrato = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["Contrato"];

    ...
}
```

Esta, entretanto não é a melhor abordagem por problemas clássicos de balanceamento de carga. A melhor abordagem envolve [implementar seu próprio gerenciador de sessões](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx), mas essa é mais complicada. Comece fazendo a primeira abordagem que é mais simples.

Comment: Até esta parte, eu já havia tentado também. O problema é que o valor virá de um DropDownList, que o usuário irá escolher. E estou com dificuldades de setar eles valor, para a Session

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Não entendi a dificuldade. Editei o código para que seu Controller receba o valor de `Contrato` via DropDown.

Comment: Você está utilizando MVC ou aspx?

Comment: Minha dúvida está na parte após a seleção do usuário.
Não irei precisar de algum método POST?

Comment: Estou usando MVC

Comment: Nesta parte, (public ActionResult Exemplo(int Contrato) {
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Contrato"] = Contrato;

    ...
}) não está recebendo valor, está nulo.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Verifique no HTML gerado se a DropDown tem o nome de `Contrato`, e se os `values` das `options` estão inteiros. O `ModelBinder` se encarrega de amarrar as variáveis pra você desde que o `<form>` esteja formatado corretamente.

Comment: Verifiquei aqui, e consegui. Obrigado Cigano Morrison Mendez.

Comment: Agora, só estou com mais um problema. A Session eu só estou conseguindo recuperar o valor, nesta view, e necessito que ela fique disponível para todo o controller. Como procedo para fazer isso?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Editei a resposta novamente.